# How to separate these circle based on their pixels mean intensity?

Tags: image-processing, image, filtering, binary, microscopy

[image]

I have this image I want to separate green circles from yellow circle in two different images whiteout changing the pixel intensity information. I used the mean intensity

```
For[jj = 1, jj < pix + 1, jj++, If[image[[ii, jj]] > 85, image[[ii, jj]] = 0.00001, 
image[[ii, jj]] = image[[ii, jj]]]]];
```

ListDensityPlot[image, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, PlotRange -> All]
I tried to make the yellow circle intensity zero (which is around 85) how can I delete the circles based on their intensity values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete pieces of an image depending on the intensity you need the raw data of the image. This can be done by "ImageData", assuming your image ist stored in "image":

```
id= ImageData[image];
```

Next we need to know how many channels your data has:

```
ImageChannels[image]
(* 4 *)
```

We have four channels. Inspection of the data in, my case (your case may be different because your image is stored differently), reveals that the forth channel is always 1 and I guess channel 1..3 are red, green blue or some other color encoding. Therefore I take the sum of channel 1..3 as measure for the intensity. With this we may zero pixels according to intensity. E.g. to get light pixels:

```
dat = Map[If[Total[#[[1 ;; 3]]] > 0.6, #, 0 #] &, id, {2}];
Image[dat]
```

[image]

For the fainter blobs this will not work as  there are faint pixels around the light blob. More evolved methods are needed for this, e.g. masking and ImageApply.

Comment: That's an interesting answer, but I'm wondering, why the black background color is kept. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Hi Urlich, I zero out  pixels with low intensity. Therefore, a black background stays black.

Comment: I got it , thank you!